# Test Case Function in JS

Tags: javascript, function

I need to create a function test case that converts from a flat class list of names to an object literal decorated with an age for each student.

The ages should be randomly generated for each student, either age 10 or age 11. Given that the age for each student is random upon each run, suggest that the tests check for age values of EITHER 10 or 11.

As an example:

```
var classList = ["Joe", "Jack", "John", "Fred", "Frank", "Barry", "Larry", "Mary",
"Harry", "Farrell", "Susan", "Monica", "Keira", "Caroline", "Harriet", "Erica",
"Luann", "Cheryl", "Beth", "Rupa", "Linda", "Allison", "Nancy", "Dora"];

var classListWithAges = [{"name":"Joe","age":11},{"name":"Jack","age":10},
{"name":"John","age":11},{"name":"Fred","age":11},{"name":"Frank","age":11},
{"name":"Barry","age":11},{"name":"Larry","age":11},{"name":"Mary","age":11},
{"name":"Harry","age":11},{"name":"Farrell","age":10},{"name":"Susan","age":10},
{"name":"Monica","age":11},{"name":"Keira","age":10},{"name":"Caroline","age":10},
{"name":"Harriet","age":11},{"name":"Erica","age":11},{"name":"Luann","age":10},
{"name":"Cheryl","age":11},{"name":"Beth","age":10},{"name":"Rupa","age":11},
{"name":"Linda","age":10},{"name":"Allison","age":10},{"name":"Nancy","age":10},
{"name":"Dora","age":10}]
```

Right now here's the starter code:

```
// See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function decorateClassListWithAges(classList) {
  // your code here
}
```

Any help how to do it? I am really confuse.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What confuses you?

Comment: Homework is fine here, but you must at least give it a try yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
function decorateClassListWithAges (classList) {
  return classList.map(name => {
    return {
      name: name,
      age: getRandomIntInclusive(10, 11)
    }
  })
}

const result = decorateClassListWithAges(classList)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function decorateClassListWithAges(classList) {
    var list = [];
    classList.map(function(n){
        list.push({ name: n, age: getRandomIntInclusive(10,11) });
    });
    return list;
}

var classListWithAges = decorateClassListWithAges(classList);
```

Comment: map already gives your result: `var classListWithAges = classList.map(x => ({ name: x, age: getRandomIntInclusive(10,11) }));`. Also hello homework!

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
function decorateClassListWithAges() {
  for (let student of classList) {
    classListWithAges.push({name: student, age: getRandomIntInclusive(10, 11)});
  }
}
```

or

```
classListWithAges = classList.map(function(student) {
  return { name: student, age: getRandomIntInclusive(10, 11) };
})
```